# VBA: Save a file with a name by default in a specific folder

Tags: excel, vba, filenames, save-as

Please I want to make a macro in Excel 2010 than the user can save a file in a specific folder but the **name** of the file would be given by default, **can not be changed by the user.** This for avoid that the user click other file looking the specific folder to save the file and the name of it change.  This is what I have:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Save
name = "File Name"
folder = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(name)
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= folder & "xlsm"
```

Comment: You can use a change event although it is worth noting that any security you implement in VBA is not really secure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to enforce this rule after coming back from the SaveAs dialog.  Since you are only interested in the folder, build your Filename like this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fso.GetParentFolderName(folder) & "\" & name & ".xlsm"
```

This requires a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime and declaring `fso` like this:

```
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
```